# Components displayed in Model Browser and received by traversing instance tree are not same

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm working on a feature where I need to get list of all components with hierarchy similar to what is displayed in 'Model' tree. I'm using  below code to traverse:

```html
tree.enumNodeChildren(
        rootId,
        function (dbId) {
          var traversingName = tree.getNodeName(dbId);
          var type = tree.getNodeType(dbId);
          console.log("Traversing Id", dbId, "Child Name", traversingName)
        },
        true
      );
```

But what I observed is, traversing using instance tree returns more nodes which are not seen in model tree. Here is the snapshot of model tree and what I get while traversing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2I8I.png)
Can someone please guide ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ModelStructurePanel will default exclude the root node from the UI if the viewer only loads one model.

Besides, it will check if the instance tree has double roots when the default root node has only one child inside. If yes, then the viewer will show the children of the children node of the root on the UI instead.

```
- Utility Knife v3 (id: 1)
  |--- Utility Knife v3 (id: 2) //!<<< Exclude this from ModelStructurePanel
    |--- Blade:1  (id: 3) //!<<<  Show nodes starting from here on the ModelStructurePanel
    |--- Blade Cradle:1  (id: 5)
    | ....
```